# Derive the Weak form of the Conservation Law Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Derive the weak form of the conservation law problem
$u_t + u^2u_x = f(x,t)$
with the initial value $u(x,0)=\cos x$**

I am trying to connect this problem with Burgers equation but failed. Anyone helps me to solve this problem? I am confused about where I need to stop. Do I need to find the formula for Rankine–Hugoniot conditions? Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: You could consider the problem as $u_t + \frac{1}{3}(u^3)_x = f(x,t)$, and then multiply by a test function and integrate to get the weak form.

Answer (score 0):

The trick has already been mentioned in the comments: Note that by the chain rule $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Bigg(\frac{1}{3} u(x,t)^3 \Bigg) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Bigg(\frac{1}{3} u(x,t)^3 \Bigg) = u_x u^2.$$

Then you are in usual business: Multiply the PDE
$$ u_t + \frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x = f(x,t)$$

with a suitable testfunction $\phi(x, t) \in C_c^1\big(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \big) $ i.e., a function that is (at least) once continuously differentiable in each variable and that vanishes outside of a compact set of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+$ to obtain
$$ \Bigg(u_t + \frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi(x, t) = f(x,t) \phi(x, t)$$

integrate over both space and time
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \Bigg(u_t + \frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi(x, t) \:\mathrm dt \:\mathrm dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f(x,t) \phi(x, t) \:\mathrm dt \:\mathrm dx$$

"Move" the derivatives (here first shown for time) onto the test function by means of integration by parts / product rule of differentiation:
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} u_t \phi(x, t) + \Bigg(\frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi(x, t) \:\mathrm dt \:\mathrm dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} -u \phi_t + \Bigg(\frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi \:\mathrm dt  + u \phi \Big \vert^\infty_0 \:\mathrm dx$$

Using compact support of $\phi$ gives for bounded $u(x,t)$: $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(x, t) \phi(x, t) = 0$
and thus
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \Bigg(u_t + \frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi(x, t) \:\mathrm dt \:\mathrm dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} -u \phi_t + \Bigg(\frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi \:\mathrm dt  - u(x, 0) \phi(x, 0) \:\mathrm dx$$
Analogous (after changing order of integration [Fubini]),
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \Bigg(\frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi(x, t)  \:\mathrm dx = \int_\mathbb{R} -\Bigg(\frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi_x  \:\mathrm dx + u\phi \Big \vert^\infty_{-\infty}$$

and again $u\phi \Big \vert^\infty_{-\infty}$ vanishes by the fact that $\phi$ has compact support.
Finally, the weak formulation is given by
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} -u \phi_t -\Bigg(\frac{1}{3} \big(u^3\big)_x \Bigg) \phi_x \:\mathrm dt  \:\mathrm dx - \int_\mathbb{R} \underbrace{u(x, 0)}_{u_0(x)} \phi(x, 0) \:\mathrm dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f(x,t) \phi(x, t) \:\mathrm dt \:\mathrm dx$$